# Normal distribution meets binomial distribution? WHAT HAVE I DONE?!

Tags: normal-distribution, binomial-distribution

So, I've been playing with a formula for the normal distribution for yucks and giggles.

$$\frac {1}{\sqrt{2 \pi\sigma^2}}e^{-\frac {x^2}{2\sigma^2}}$$

And I decided to look at 10 binary trials (coin toss) and, you know, list the chances of getting no heads, one head, two heads, etc.{1,10,45,120,210,252,210,120,45,10,1}, the appropriate row of Pascal's triangle.

I put these as points on a graph, indexing them on x {-5...5}. Because this gave me a crazy-tall graph I divided everything by 252 so it would max out at 1.

(Link to Desmos graph.) https://www.desmos.com/calculator/xye7h54upl

I then figured the variance at about 0.26

Then I wanted to fit the curve of the normal distribution on the dots representing the binary trials.  Playing around, I realized that I could create a perfect match if I put the right amount in the numerator and let x and y take on a set of values from the coin toss distribution.

Recasting the equation gave me:

$$m=ye^{\frac {x^2}{2\sigma^2}}\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}$$

Where 'm' is the factor by which I need to multiply the whole equation to get a perfect fit.  Which I did! I think.  When m = about 4.1, the normal distribution fits the data as perfectly as need be. (used the most precise values available to me on the graph)

BUT, to get it to work, I had to multiply the variance by 10.  I don't know why.

Also, what did I just do?  What does (approx) 4.1 mean?  WHAT HAVE I DONE?

Comment: I believe you had discovered the central limit theorem.